# Were monasteries a refuge for mentally handicapped adults?

Tags: religion, monastery

I cannot find a citation but I believe I read a quote by Galton that indicated this. I know this was not the sole function of such places but it makes sense to me that a borderline mentally handicapped individual might be placed in a sheltered environment, maybe by richer parents who made a contribution to the order in exchange for them taking care of their adult offspring or even it was a place where homeless people who obviously could not find regular work were sometimes sheltered.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, one of the functions of [monasteries](https://historicengland.org.uk/research/inclusive-heritage/disability-history/1050-1485/) (and convents) were as places to care for sick and disabled people, as part of their religious mission. This function helped set the precedent for today's hospitals.

Comment: So would a mentally handicapped person be understood as someone who would not just be cared for but potentially would become a monk?

Comment: @Jeff: That, I don't know.

Comment: Just visualizing it, I can't imagine them not making someone capable of basic monkish functions a monk rather than a permanent "guest."

Comment: If one was capable of performing basic, probably menial, chores, then a place would be made available. The person was in fact *paying their way*.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens: Were they then considered a monk or some other status and what was that called?

Comment: @Jeff There were [lay brothers and sisters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lay_brother), who were not ordained but worked as members of the community (often illiterate manual workers), but these would have been largely distinct from those benefiting from the hospital services.

Comment: @Jeff: The church was (mostly) a meritocracy the same way the Royal Navy was. One could buy in as *midshipman* or be pressed or volunteered as a *landsman* but after that promotion was based on technical merit and success.

Answer (score 1):

All ordained priests until recently have been required to be able to read, write, and speak Latin, and to be able to study and to pass examinations in Philosophy, Theology, and Liturgy conducted in Latin, which requires an advanced level of fluency in that language. Although some of the monks who were lay brothers might indeed have been intellectually challenged, the ordained priests among the monks would have been intellectually quite competent.

Comment: Welcome to History:SE. Sources to support your assertions would greatly improve this answer.

Comment: That assertion does not match with multiple historical sources.

Comment: This seems to be a comment directed to the chain of comments below Tom's answer, not an answer itself.